# maintaining user authentication if i have some web pages on mod_python and some on mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, mod-python

I have a web application written in raw python and hosted on apache using mod_python. I am building another web application which is django based and will be hosted on same server using mod_wsgi.

Now, the scenerio is such that user will login from the web page which is using mod_python and a link will send him to my application which will be using mod_wsgi. My question is how can I maintain session? I need the same authentication to work for my application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django with mod_wsgi and a raw python page which only serve a link to django application, you don't need to maintain session on both page. When user click on first link and reach the django application, just check session there.

Django have session_db which use memcache. More information can be found here: 
[Django Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568/django-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

SSO across web applications is poorly supported. One thing you can look at is:

http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/

What you can do is really going to depend though on what authentication database you are currently using in the mod_python application and how you are remembering that someone is logged in. If you can provide that information, may be able to suggest other things.

Comment: due to some reason, i have to pause my wrk 4 few days.. I will ask ur favour when I resume dis wrk.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually: store a cookie using your raw python web page that you process in a "welcome" view or custom middleware class in Django, and insert them into the sessions db. This is basically what hungnv suggests.

The most ridiculous way to do this would be to figure out how Django deals with sessions and session cookies, insert the correct row into Django's session database from your raw python app, and then custom-set the session cookie using Django's auth functions.